# Opening Ubuntu Terminal with Shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Let's say, I write some stuff on terminal.Then I minimize it and start to work in some other applications.Then if I type `(**ctrl + alt + T**`) then a new terminal gets opened.But i want my previous terminal to be opened.Is there any way I can do it ?

(I am using Ubuntu 20.04. And I am aware about **guake** .Can i do it using the built in **ubuntu terminal**.)

Comment: @matigo ,  Alt + Tab opens all the opened apps on the same workspace including the terminal i am looking for.But I want some keybinding which will open directly my desired Terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible.

- First disable the default shortcut for opening a terminal ("Launch terminal" under "Launchers" in the "Keyboard" settings"
- Then create your custom shortcut key to open a terminal. Click the "+" at the bottom of the list of "Custom Shortcuts", then fill out "Terminal" as name (or anything else), and `sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Gnome-terminal || gnome-terminal"` as command. Set the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or any shortcut of your choice.

This uses the utility `wmctrl` to first check whether a window of Gnome terminal exists, and switch to it if it does. If such window does not exist, it launches the terminal. You therefore need to install `wmctrl` first.

**Solution on steroids**

Use [jumpapp](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp). This is a script that uses `wmctrl`. You can switch between all open windows by repeatedly pressing the shortcut key.